# How do I turn these values from MYSQL into an array

Tags: wp-query, array, php

I am working on a custom query to show a few posts.  I am able to output all the post ID's.  I am trying to turn these ID's into an array so I can use 'post__in'      => $myarray in my query.  How can I do this?

```
          <?php
            $allposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `music_id` FROM `custom_table` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
              foreach ($allposts as $singlepost) {
                       echo '<p>' .$singlepost->music_id. '</p>';
              }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$wpdb->get_col](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Column). It will return a one-dimensional array that you can use in    `post__in`

```
$allposts = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT `music_id` FROM `custom_table` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
```

Comment: Hey thank you Shane.  This works great and is the most simple solution.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = array();
 foreach ($allposts as $singlepost) {
      $id[]= $singlepost->music_id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This seems to be working.  I had to add this

`$recentlistens = array($id[0], $id[1], $id[2], $id[3],$id[4]);`

Is there a better way to do that?